# How do I make a blue square image in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[image]

I need a blue square image before the text total.
Please see the attached image.
How do I do this in angular js.
ng-style is not taking height and width. I am not able to do it with ng-class applying css.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
 <div ng-style="{'width':'20px', 'height':'20px', 'position':'relative', 'float':'left', 'background-color':'blue', 'margin-right': '5px'}"></div>Total
```

see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykqfgLwc/)